# STM32F103 SPI MISO doesn't work as expected

Tags: stm32, spi, flash-memories

In one of my small projects I use STMF103C8T6 as MCU and SPI memory W25Q128 of Winbond to store a data. The memory chip connected to SPI1. Here is a part of the scheme:
[image]

The code is mostly generated by CubeMX. I've only added some code to communicate with the memory chip:

**Initialization:**

```cpp
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}
```

**W25Q128 code:**

```cpp
#define CS_Pin GPIO_PIN_3
#define CS_GPIO_Port GPIOA
#define ChipSelect() HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_GPIO_Port, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET)
#define ChipDeselect() HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_GPIO_Port, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET)

#define COMMAND_IDENTIFICATION 0x90

uint8_t buffer_tx[4];
uint8_t buffer_rx[2];

uint16_t GetIdentification()
{
    buffer_tx[0] = COMMAND_IDENTIFICATION;
    buffer_tx[1] = 0x0;
    buffer_tx[2] = 0x0;
    buffer_tx[3] = 0x0;

    ChipSelect();
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, buffer_tx, 4, 1000); // send 0x90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, buffer_rx, 2, 1000); // receive 0xFF, 0xFF 
    ChipDeselect();
    return ((uint8_t)buffer_rx[0] << 8) | (uint8_t)buffer_rx[1];
}

int main(void)
{
    MX_SPI1_Init();
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    uint16_t id = GetIdentification();
    printf("Manufacturer ID: 0x%.4X\r\n", id);
    while 
    {
    }   
}
```

According to the datasheet to get chip manufacturer code I need to send 0x90 and 3 dummy bytes. The chip should return 0xEF, 0x17. But for some reason I receive 2 bytes of **0xFF**. Ok, I've changed the chip twice in the PCB but without results. I still receive 0xFF, 0xFF. I've connected logic analyzer to the chip on the PCB and to my astonishment I get the following picture:

[image]

According to the diagram everything is Ok. The chip sends 0xEF, 0x17 as expected. But for some reason my STM32 doesn't see that.

I've rechecked the PCB, I reinstalled a few chips, I've tried W25Q128 and W25Q64 - all failed, I receive only 0xFF, 0xFF instead of real data. What could it be and how can I fix that?

The full project is [here](https://easyeda.com/account/project?project=7b1f77cb479c40568660854e0ddf500f).

Comment: Verify that you have the correct GPIO and alternate function configuration for all the pins, something that does not seem to appear in your posted code.  Try manipulating the MISO pin with something else, for example a pulling resistor, and verify that you can capture its state.  Also try to read the state as a GPIO (or even program it to toggle as a GPIO output).  Double check the soldering of the MCU, especially (but not only) if this is a custom board.

Comment: Also, read the chip's data sheet about the #WP & #HOLD pin functions. Both are active low, you pulled it to GND, so they are both active. That may or may not do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because #HOLD pin is grounded so the W25Q128 is in HOLD mode. #HOLD pin should be connected to 3.3V to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Justme, looks like you're right. Most likely I've make an error somehow in PCB. But I am very interested in one question - why the logic analyzer shows the chip response?